# How to find patterns of time trends in repeated cross-sections

Tags: time-series, panel-data

I'm currently analyzing public opinion using a large, population-based dataset. Data were collected in multiple regions in several waves (e.g. 2000, 2006, 2012), with a new sample being drawn in every wave. The dataset looks something like this, although with multiple cases per region/wave:

```
id region wave dep_var
1       A 2000  4
2       A 2006  5
3       A 2012  7
4       B 2000  7
5       B 2006  2
6       B 2012  4
7       C 2000  5
8       C 2006  3
9       C 2012  4
```

Hence, data are technically not longitudinal, but still contain information on evolution of opinion in different regions. Now I'm looking for a way to group regions according to the evolution of opinion (dep_var) over time, i.e. identifying classes of regions that share similar time trends (for example one class with increase in dep_var, one with no change and one with decrease in dep_var). Of course I could analyze mean differences between waves per region and then manually group the results, but I was wondering whether there is a more efficient way of doing this. I was thinking of applying some form of growth curve modeling, but this usually requires paired, longitudinal data.

Any ideas on this? Thanks in advance!